# How can i make other parts of a model move during animation while the main body have physics?

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

Here is my situation: i have character that is a sphere (body) with another sphere inside (brain) and the surface of the body there are two discs (eyes) and another one (mouth).
The rig start from the center (body_bone) from there i extrude 4 more bones.
[image]

The physics should be apply only on the body but the other parts still need to follow the movement (example a jump: the physics will apply on the main body but the other parts will still follow the movement up and down of the jump).
The problem is that when i creat an animation the parts follow the movement of the animation but the main body don't.[image][image]

Here is screen of my hierarchy

[image]

How can i fix it? If there is a need for more image or information i will add more.

here is the link to the file

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you parent the armature to the body?

Comment: no change when I run the animation, the children do not move with the parent. I mean it does kinda follow the animation up and down but it's all desynch. Like the main bone and it's children with the objects follow the animation but the main sphere do what it want kinda. but if don't use any physics it works fine

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You did not mention which physical simulation you are using. Are you using both Cloth and Soft Body at the same time? (see outliner, last screenshot) - Have you tried vertex parent or object parent?

Comment: yes both. the cloth was the closest to the effect that i wanted  but i wanted some jiggle that soft body gave me. yes i have tried both

Comment: @moonboots i added the file

Comment: So i'm not sure that parenting the armature to a soft body would work but you could try to parent to 3 of its vertices: Select the armature, shift select the body, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices and Ctrl P > Parent to Vertex

Comment: doesn't work if i click the armature first and then shift select the body in edit mode goes the armature i can't select vertex. If i do the inverse there is a loop in the parenting.

Answer (score 0):

In *Object* mode, unparent the body object (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear Parent*), choose either *Cloth* or *Soft Body* (if you choose *Cloth* disable the *Pressure* option, if you choose *Soft Body* disable the *Goal* option), close the armature action in the *Dope Sheet*, select your armature, shift select your body object, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 of its vertices and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]